# Automate Apache Configuration Deployment

Tags: apache, deployment, ssh

I need to find a way to automate the deployment of my apache configuration to a few servers. I make change frequently on apache/conf/... etc, and I usually do this manually by copying files to each servers and restart apache servers.

It would be nice if I could give svn directory link with revision number, and it automates the deployment process.

I'm just wondering if there is an out of box tool that could achieve this with little configuration.

Because I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there is an out of box tool.I heard about fabric but it still need a ton of configuration(customize scripts) to achieve what I need to do.I know I could write some sort of bash scripts from scratch and a web app to do this.

Do you have any recommended tools/software that I should look into?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for configuration management software. Puppet is one example

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_(software)

There are others such as Ansible, Salt and Chef